# How to pass multiple event type ids as query parameter in OneLogin get-events API

Tags: api, events, get, onelogin

I am trying to do this:

```
https://api.us.onelogin.com/api/1/events?event_type_id=13,14
```

but it only returns event types of 13. Is there any way to accomplish that?